# How to show multiple GetX snackbars at once

Tags: flutter-getx

I want to popup multiple snackbars like they are on top of eachother.

Is there a way to do that ?

```
Get.snackbar(
   "test",
   "test",
    backgroundColor: secondaryColor,
    maxWidth: 350,
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: Get.height * 0.95),
    isDismissible: false,
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not show popup as stack.. with Get.snackbar because the Concept of Get is a Context less Widget tree. and for dialogue popup with Get each dialogue is created separated and show one and after such as ques FIFO.. for that approaches you need to think out side the Get then you will get your desire result

Happy Coding.... :)